# Is it possible to implement a default soundcloud user?

Tags: android, soundcloud

I am implementing a pure Holo Soundcloud app and I would like to avoid having to authenticate the users as soon as they open the app the first time.
This kind of connection wall puts off a lot of users that simply close the app and never open it again.

Since I need an authenticated user to interact with the Soundcloud API, can I create a 'dummy'  account used by all my users until they authenticate ?
This account would be able to consult the list of hot songs and use the player, but unable to share sounds, like a track or do anything else that suppose a real user account (and be presented with the connection screen instead).

Is it something possible with the Soundcloud API or will I encounter a limit (for example on the number of people that can use the account at the same time) ?

Comment: Seems more like a question for Soundcloud... I know that this is technologically possible because I've done it. But I never distributed the app so I have no idea what kind of rate limits they may impose.

Comment: @FoamyGuy I am asking here because Soundcloud use Stackoverflow to answer their third party devs questions. I could probably also mail them directly but that way everyone can profit from the answer.

Technologically it is indeed easy to achieve, I just want to be sure that I won't get my dev key revoked because of this.

Comment: I'm not from soundcloud, but they do have some fuzzy rate limiting in place. (tiny bit of reference [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#errors) and [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/terms-of-use#quotas)) They won't care who makes the calls, just how many times they're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to be authenticated to access much of the API. Only the actions you'd expect, actually: things like getting the current user, their current tracks, editing, favoriting, uploading etc. Getting hot tracks, playing tracks, finding all the tracks and playlists of a user, etc, don't need any authentication.

Comment: Are you really sure of that ?
wrapper = new ApiWrapper(client_id, client_secret, null, null, Env.LIVE);
HttpResponse response = wrapper.get(Request.to("/tracks").with("order","hotness"));
generates error 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Quite sure http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&order=hotness&limit=3 Check the actual request being made. Does it contain a valid client_id, because AFAIK that's the only reason `tracks` would respond 401.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it allowed me to understand the problem clearly. The javi api wrapper provided by Soundcloud seems to do not work when you are not authentified. I did not have the time to search why yet, but building the request myself with   HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&order=hotness&limit=3");

   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   response = client.execute(request);
works perfectly.